# What's the difference between the ::after and ::backdrop pseudo-elements?

Tags: css

Well, what the title says.

I really couldn't find any detailed information on it, the MDN documentation is also rather sparse if not useless..

Can you possibly give examples and tips when one is preferred over the other?

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::backdrop)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised. The Fullscreen API isn't even finished, much less supported. (Whatever bits of it that are there *are* supported here and there.)

Comment: @BoltClock the motivation should still be clear.

Comment: Yeah - I'm just saying you're going to be hard-pressed to find an answer beyond "::backdrop is part of the work-in-progress Fullscreen API and is completely unrelated to generated content (::before and ::after)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This pseudo-element is a box rendered immediately below the element
>   (and above the element below the element in the stack, if any), within
>   the same top layer.

As you see in the documentation you mentioned, it will add a **new element** between your actual element and the element after.

With `::after` you can insert content after the **content** of your selected element (so the content is still add to the same element), see this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_after_style).

[Pseudo element after documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp):

> Insert content before, or after, the content of an element

Over that, there is a difference in what browsers can render the pseudo elements: [Backdrop](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Abackdrop) vs. [After](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Aafter). As you can see, today (2016-02-19) you can use `::backdrop` only in chrome, opera and android browser.

Comment: Can you give an example when ::backdrop would be preferred? Not seeing **any** working examples on the web by the way, although browser support is there. Curious